# From where to learn the basics of Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, business-intelligence

I am new to SQL Server 2005 and want to start from the basics with examples.
Could anyone guide me how can I proceed. As my target is to learn Businness Intelligence[BI], what I need to concentrate to get the sufficient knowledge to walk into BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SqlZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) to get up to speed on sql.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use sql server 2008? I think there are more options in sql 2008 then in the 2005 version.

Check this link for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167593.aspx